# Draw all 12 axes when using ax.scatter for a 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I want to draw all 12 axes when using `ax.scatter` for a 3D scatter plot

Here is my code. As you see my axes lines are not matching the range of `ax.scatter`. How can I achieve that?

`ax.get_xlim(`) etc. does not retrieve the exact limits that `ax.scatter` has used.

Here is the content of `data.txt`: https://pastebin.com/raw/hU4NhGQc

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_path = 'data.txt'

col_widths = [12, 13, 18, 13, 13, 16, 16, 15, 16, 15]

data = pd.read_fwf(file_path, widths=col_widths, header=0)

columns_to_format = ['Sum', 'Mean', 'Std', 'Min', 'Max']
for col in columns_to_format:
    data[col] = data[col].apply(lambda x: '{:14.8e}'.format(float(x)) if pd.notnull(x) else x)

net_data = data[data['Variable'] == '__net'].copy()

net_data['b'] = net_data['b'].replace({'10^11': 1e11, '10^13': 1e13})

c_floats = net_data['Mean'].astype(float).to_numpy()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = net_data['x'].astype(float).to_numpy()
y = net_data['y'].astype(float).to_numpy()
z = net_data['b'].astype(float).to_numpy()

point_size = 50  
img = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c_floats, s=point_size, cmap='jet', vmin=c_floats.min(), vmax=c_floats.max() )
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('b')

x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
z_min, z_max = ax.get_zlim()

ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_min], color='black')
ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color='black')
ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_max, z_max], color='black')
ax.plot([x_min, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color='black')

ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color='black')
ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_min], color='black')
ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color='black')
ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_max, z_max], color='black')

ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_max], color='black')
ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_min, y_min], [z_min, z_max], color='black')
ax.plot([x_min, x_min], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_max], color='black')
ax.plot([x_max, x_max], [y_max, y_max], [z_min, z_max], color='black')

offset = 0.01  
for (i, txt) in enumerate(c_floats):
    ax.text(x[i] + offset, y[i] + offset, z[i] + offset, '{:6.4f}'.format(txt), size=6, zorder=1, color='k')

elev = 45  
azim = 45  
ax.view_init(elev=elev, azim=azim)

cbar = fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, shrink=0.5)
cbar.set_label('Mean')

plot_save_path = 'plot.png'
fig.savefig(plot_save_path, dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

And here is the produced plot:

[image]